# Not able to compile JSP files in JBoss 5.1 with Java 1.8

Tags: java, jsp, java-8, jboss5.x

Not able to compile JSP files in JBoss 5.1 with Java 1.8.
Able to compile regular Java files and even complete Spring project which does not have JSPs.

It is working properly, if we kept compiled class files for those JSP files.

Following is the error I am getting when I am trying to run a JSP file:

```
2016-07-15 14:56:00,758 ERROR [org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler] (http-0.0.0.0-80-31) Compilation error
org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFormatException
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.classfmt.ClassFileReader.<init>(ClassFileReader.java:369)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:206)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler$1.findType(JDTCompiler.java:163)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.LookupEnvironment.askForType(LookupEnvironment.java:97)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.UnresolvedReferenceBinding.resolve(UnresolvedReferenceBinding.java:49)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.BinaryTypeBinding.resolveType(BinaryTypeBinding.java:101)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.PackageBinding.getTypeOrPackage(PackageBinding.java:169)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.lookup.Scope.getType(Scope.java:2241)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:974)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.TypeDeclaration.resolve(TypeDeclaration.java:1184)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.ast.CompilationUnitDeclaration.resolve(CompilationUnitDeclaration.java:535)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.process(Compiler.java:743)
        at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:444)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:429)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:300)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve.invoke(RequestDumperValve.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
2016-07-15 14:56:01,873 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/].[jsp]] (http-0.0.0.0-80-31) Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP:

An error occurred at line: 1 in the generated java file
The type java.io.ObjectInputStream cannot be resolved. It is indirectly referenced from required .class files

Stacktrace:
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:439)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:335)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:313)
        at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:300)
        at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:585)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:312)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:322)
        at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:249)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.filters.ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ReplyHeaderFilter.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:235)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityAssociationValve.java:190)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:92)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.process(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:126)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.invoke(SecurityContextEstablishmentValve.java:70)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
        at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:158)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:567)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve.invoke(RequestDumperValve.java:151)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:330)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:829)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:598)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to remove the jasper-jdt.jar from JBoss 5.1. You would find in the following:

> jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\jasper-jdt.jar

I had a similar problem using jasperreport library with JBoss 5.1 AS and jdk 1.8 (no problem with jdk 1.7).

I resolved removing the jasper-jdt.jar from JBoss 5.1. 
In my project pom I put the dependecy to updated  Eclipse Compiler for Java (ECJ) but until I removed the jasper-jdt.jar the problem remains:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>eclipse</groupId>
                <artifactId>jdtcore</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler</groupId>
        <artifactId>ecj</artifactId>
        <version>4.5.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I was in trouble with jboss-5.1.0.GA due an old application made with jsp (old version). I knew that jbossweb is the place where jsp are compiled. So, I compared the structure of jasper-jdt.jar with the ecj-4.3.1.jar and notice that both are very similar. Then, I applied ecj-4.3.1.jar in place (replace) of jasper-jdt.jar renaming ecj-4.3.1.jar to jasper-jdt.jar. After running the replacement was sucessfull.

Answer (score 1):

Try to setup *JAVA_HOME* environment variable pointing to the *JDK*. *JBoss* should be able to pick up `tools.jar` into the `classpath` and use that instead of *JDT* for compiling