# JBOSS 4.2.1 and JRE1.8.1xx is compatible? JBoss-4.2.1GA jsp problems

Tags: java, jsp, jboss

We have and product which is has 1.6.xxx jre ,4.2.1 jboss and jasperserver,

I tried to compile jre 1.8.xxx and build succesfull.  First, When I try to login page  , had an 404 error.

[Not able to compile JSP files in JBoss 5.1 with Java 1.8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38399796/not-able-to-compile-jsp-files-in-jboss-5-1-with-java-1-8)

Now , i have an different error. The login page is comming white screen :(

its jboss log,

```
2018-02-06 13:44:33,139 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/local-login].[jsp]] Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.login_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:598)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.forwardToLoginPage(FormAuthenticator.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at com.nortel.ems.mgmt.quantum.webagent.security.sso.tomcat.valve.SecureHttpRequestResponseValve.doSpecialHandling(SecureHttpRequestResponseValve.java:312)
    at com.nortel.ems.mgmt.quantum.webagent.security.sso.tomcat.valve.AbstractValveBase.invoke(AbstractValveBase.java:130)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2018-02-06 13:44:33,139 WARN  [org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator] Unexpected error forwarding to login page
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:156)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:320)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:266)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:803)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:687)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:469)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:403)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.forwardToLoginPage(FormAuthenticator.java:316)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.FormAuthenticator.authenticate(FormAuthenticator.java:244)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:491)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.security.JaccContextValve.invoke(JaccContextValve.java:84)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:128)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at com.nortel.ems.mgmt.quantum.webagent.security.sso.tomcat.valve.SecureHttpRequestResponseValve.doSpecialHandling(SecureHttpRequestResponseValve.java:312)
    at com.nortel.ems.mgmt.quantum.webagent.security.sso.tomcat.valve.AbstractValveBase.invoke(AbstractValveBase.java:130)
    at org.jboss.web.tomcat.service.jca.CachedConnectionValve.invoke(CachedConnectionValve.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.SingleSignOn.invoke(SingleSignOn.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:241)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:844)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:580)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:447)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to load class for JSP
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:600)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.getServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:144)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jsp.login_jsp
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:134)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:66)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.load(JspCompilationContext.java:598)
    ... 27 more
```

In my opinion , jsp compiler not work. Can you solve this problem?

Thanks

Comment: IMHO - you're likely to run into a lot of issues trying to use JDK8 with Jboss 4.2.  I believe JBoss 7 technically doesnt officially support JDK8 - but I have numerous instances running under JDK8

Answer (score 0):

spent a few hours trying to find the solution today. Checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19963052/java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-jsp-index-jsp) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21108105/http-status-500-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-org-apache-jsp-index-jsp/36378567) which looked similar and at least provided some thoughts.

However, it appeared that none of those seem to apply to my case.

Faced exactly the same error stack in the `server.log` of Jboss 4.2.3 running on ancient RHEL4 machine with Java 6. So, decided to post my solution here, because it really helped me and nothing like that was mentioned in the above questions.

Finally, I realized (with the help of `df -h`) that `/var` partition (which is used for JBoss deployments) was 100% full, and likely something was not linked properly during the latest JBoss restart (or in the runtime) due to this.

I have just **freed up some space and rebooted the server**, that's it.